# AJAX Chat scrolling box extra pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I finally figured how to to disable chat scrolling when user scrolls up to read, and continue scrolling once hes at bottom.

But I am having 1 problem, the chat adds extra 17px, when I add a size to each post. the 17px never changes, no matter what size i set.

There is my code:

```
scrollTop + divHeight : scrollHeight : amountOfPosts

809 : 792 : 11
881 : 864 : 12
```

See everyone the scrollTop + height is greather that scrollHeight, its only by 17px. My question is, what is adding these 17px? I need to know that to dynamically add the 17px to my chat, and not manually.

See this live jsfildde example: http://jsfiddle.net/Yp33R/

Comment: I possibly think that the 17px is the margin between the posts, but I am not sure what causes them.

Answer (score 0):

That 17px would be the height of your horizontal scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

It is the `<br />` element you have added within your javascript. Simply remove it, it is not required

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/Yp33R/1/

Change

```
$("#sub").click(function() {
        am++;
        var m = $("#form").val();
        obj.html(obj.html() + "<div id='post'>" + m + "</div><br />");
```

To

```
$("#sub").click(function() {
        am++;
        var m = $("#form").val();
        obj.html(obj.html() + "<div id='post'>" + m + "</div>");
```

Also remove the `height: 50px;` that you have set on `#post` within your CSS. This is auto and does not need setting.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/Yp33R/3/

Comment: Exactly when I found out, thank you for the answer ;).

Comment: I did, but even in your jsfiddle, there is still 17px, even without the <br />

Comment: Fixed it, it' was the height of the bottom scroll bar, overflow-y: hidden;